# facebook manipulate image from link service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if you paste a link in a private message in facebook, it will do this thing where it gets the biggest image off that site. is there any way to create a script that will call the facebook servers with a given url and get returned a link with javascript?

the idea is to create something which you input a given url in and it will return the url of the image.

Comment: why not do it on your own? curl that url and parse html for any image desired. Why involve facebook in this?

Comment: because.. it would be hard to do in javascript (same origin policy) and why set up a server for it if facebook already has servers for it with everything done already?

Comment: if you want to access things at facebook from a different server you can still face cross origin policy, except for Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is when you put a URL in facebook comment/message/post, facebook tries to give its users more than just a URL string which is very hard to read, giving no idea about what the link might say.

So to avoid this difficulty and give user more info about the link without visiting the link itself, facebook access the content of that URL parse it their way and get meta content from it, if meta data is missing they'll parse some other images off the web page and they simply present it in better way.

About your question if I understand your goal correctly, you don't need to involve facebook in this, simply write a server side (PHP script) to get details of the URL and use it. You can finds tons of such scripts.

Doing it in PHP will have no issue about CORS. Give it a try do something if you still face a problem present your try here at stackoverflow. I am sure thousands of users will help you in your problems.

Cheers